# Pax Web on Knopflerfish on Android

Tags: java, android, osgi-bundle, knopflerfish, pax-web

I'm planning to start `OSGi` on Android with Web Services, wherein I will be able to run Java Server Pages (jsp) and Java Servlets on Android Browser.

My initial step was installing `Knopflerfish` on Android. I have followed this tutorial from knopflerfish: http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/5.0.0/docs/android_dalvik_tutorial.html

Knopflerfish did well, I have seen the localhost:8080 on the Android phone's browser.

My second step was to install `Pax Web` on Knopflerfish that was also installed on Android. I have also followed their tutorial from here: http://www.knopflerfish.org/kf_pax_web_tutorial.html

The tutorial said that:

> Uninstall the KF HTTP bundles
>
> The first step is to stop the HTTP root bundle and uninstall the JSDK and HTTP-server bundles as PaxWeb will take over this function. Normally you will most likely also want to uninstall the HTTP-root-bundle, but for this tutorial we will leave it installed. Make sure to do a refresh packages before going to the next step.

Then:

> Install PaxWeb
>
> The second step is install and start the following bundles from PaxWeb.
>
> - pax-web-jsp-1.0.2.jar (install)
> - pax-web-jetty-bundle-1.0.2.jar (install & start)
> - pax-web-extender-war-0.8.0.jar(install & start)

The `Pax Web` bundles were successfully installed.

---

**Problem**

The `Pax Web` bundles cannot be started.

It gives me this error messages on the console when I try to start `HTTP-root-IMP` which is a Knopflerfish bundle.

```
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent bundle #20
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent throwable:
Couldn't start bundle: HTTP-root-IMPL (#20) (due to: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#20, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
org.osgi.service.http;version=[1.1.0,2.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - org.osgi.service.http;version=1.2.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=[2.5.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=[2.5.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#20, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
org.osgi.service.http;version=[1.1.0,2.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - org.osgi.service.http;version=1.2.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=[2.5.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=[2.5.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.getUpdatedState(BundleImpl.java:1259)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.finalizeActivation(BundleImpl.java:312)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.PermissionOps.callFinalizeActivation(PermissionOps.java:265)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:295)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.frameworkcommands.FrameworkCommandGroup.cmdStart(FrameworkCommandGroup.java:1634)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at org.knopflerfish.service.console.CommandGroupAdapter.execute(CommandGroupAdapter.java:256)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command$2.run(Command.java:239)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command.run(Command.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

Another is when I will start the bundles from the `Pax Web` tutorial from Knopflerfish. Here I tried to start `pax-web-jetty-bundle-1.0.2.jar (OPS4J Pax Web - Jetty Bundle)`:

```
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent bundle #16
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent throwable:
Couldn't start bundle: OPS4J Pax Web - Jetty Bundle (#16) (due to: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#16, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
javax.security.sasl -- No providers found.
javax.management.remote -- No providers found.
javax.management.modelmbean -- No providers found.
javax.management -- No providers found.)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#16, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
javax.security.sasl -- No providers found.
javax.management.remote -- No providers found.
javax.management.modelmbean -- No providers found.
javax.management -- No providers found.
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.getUpdatedState(BundleImpl.java:1259)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.finalizeActivation(BundleImpl.java:312)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.PermissionOps.callFinalizeActivation(PermissionOps.java:265)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:295)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.frameworkcommands.FrameworkCommandGroup.cmdStart(FrameworkCommandGroup.java:1634)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at org.knopflerfish.service.console.CommandGroupAdapter.execute(CommandGroupAdapter.java:256)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command$2.run(Command.java:239)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command.run(Command.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

Lastly, when I try to run `pax-web-extender-war-0.8.0.jar (OPS4J Pax Web - Extender - War)` this error messages will also appear:

```
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent bundle #17
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent throwable:
Couldn't start bundle: OPS4J Pax Web - Extender - WAR (#17) (due to: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#17, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
org.osgi.service.http;version=[1.0.0,2.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - org.osgi.service.http;version=1.2.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=2.1.0 -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=2.1.0 -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#17, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
org.osgi.service.http;version=[1.0.0,2.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - org.osgi.service.http;version=1.2.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=2.1.0 -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=2.1.0 -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.getUpdatedState(BundleImpl.java:1259)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.finalizeActivation(BundleImpl.java:312)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.PermissionOps.callFinalizeActivation(PermissionOps.java:265)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:295)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.frameworkcommands.FrameworkCommandGroup.cmdStart(FrameworkCommandGroup.java:1634)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at org.knopflerfish.service.console.CommandGroupAdapter.execute(CommandGroupAdapter.java:256)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command$2.run(Command.java:239)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command.run(Command.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

I also tried to start `pax-web-jsp-1.0.2.jar (OPS4J Pax Web - Jsp Support)` this error message was displayed:

```
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent bundle #15
[stderr] ## DEBUG: errors - FrameworkErrorEvent throwable:
Couldn't start bundle: OPS4J Pax Web - Jsp Support (#15) (due to: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#15, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
javax.tools -- No providers found.
javax.servlet.resources;version=[2.3.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.resources;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=[2.3.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=[2.3.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.lang.model.util -- No providers found.
javax.lang.model.type -- No providers found.
javax.lang.model.element -- No providers found.
javax.lang.model -- No providers found.
javax.annotation.processing -- No providers found.)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle#15, unable to resolve: Missing package(s) or can not resolve all of the them:
javax.tools -- No providers found.
javax.servlet.resources;version=[2.3.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.resources;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=[2.3.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=[2.3.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.lang.model.util -- No providers found.
javax.lang.model.type -- No providers found.
javax.lang.model.element -- No providers found.
javax.lang.model -- No providers found.
javax.annotation.processing -- No providers found.
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.getUpdatedState(BundleImpl.java:1259)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.finalizeActivation(BundleImpl.java:312)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.PermissionOps.callFinalizeActivation(PermissionOps.java:265)
        at org.knopflerfish.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:295)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.frameworkcommands.FrameworkCommandGroup.cmdStart(FrameworkCommandGroup.java:1634)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at org.knopflerfish.service.console.CommandGroupAdapter.execute(CommandGroupAdapter.java:256)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command$2.run(Command.java:239)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
        at org.knopflerfish.bundle.console.Command.run(Command.java:226)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

---

From what I have understood from the error messages, the bundles were looking for these packages. Is there any way I can resolve this and be able to successfully run a Java Web Application on Android with OSGi framework?

```
org.osgi.service.http;version=[1.1.0,2.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - org.osgi.service.http;version=1.2.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet.http;version=[2.5.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet.http;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].
javax.servlet;version=[2.5.0,3.0.0) -- Could not resolve exporting bundle - javax.servlet;version=2.5.0 Bundle[id=16,gen=0].

javax.security.sasl -- No providers found.
javax.management.remote -- No providers found.
javax.management.modelmbean -- No providers found.
javax.management -- No providers found.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I strongly suggest to use the same version for all bundles of Pax-Web, second you're missing a servlet API bundle. Also it looks like you're also missing a couple of other Pax-Web bundles. You'll most likely need the following bundles:

- pax-web-api
- pax-web-jetty-bundle
- pax-web-jsp
- pax-web-runtime
- pax-web-spi

and if you want to use wars you'll need the

- pax-web-extender-war
- pax-url-war
- and a couple more ...

Latest version of Pax-Web is 3.0.2 so you should choose with care depending on what you're trying to do. You might find it helpful to check the ITests of Pax-Web (depending on the version you're going to use) for inspiration on which bundles are needed. 
I'd suggest to start with a minimum set. This way you start with the http-service first and enhance it to the needs you have.

Take a look at the [Pax-Web project at Github](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/) and especially at the samples and itests modules for more details.

Comment: I have successfully downloaded pax-web jar files here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ops4j/pax/web/. But one of the steps to add these jar filed on the current project I am doing is to `dexify` it, but I cannot create a dex file of `pax-web-jetty-bundle-3.0.2.jar`. I need a dex file of the jar files before I include them to the current project.

Comment: what could you recommend for servlet API bundle? @Achim

Comment: You'll find a karaf features file (the list of needed bundles) at https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-features/src/main/resources/features.xml#L4, this will get you a bit further I hope.